# How to determine which classes are accessible in a PHP file?

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I have this huge code base, which uses `require`s, `include`s and autoloading all over the place. I need to determine which classes are accessible from one particular file. Unfortunately, building and running the app is a huge hustle and I want to avoid it as much as possible. How can I determine quickly which classes can be used inside that file without additional `require`s?

Comment: If you use an autoloader *ALL* classes are available.

Comment: @MarkusZeller No, only those that autoloader makes available and I have trouble figuring out if an autoloader is included or not.

Comment: `class_exists()` ?

Comment: @MichaelQuad I can't run the code.

Comment: What kind of autoloader should that be not making all classes available? This question lacks any data for possible debugging.